# delete nth row from table (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know its possible to select nth row.

For example

```
select from table limit 1 offset 3;
```

Is it possible to delete nth row?

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the *nth* row in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an `id` and something to `order by` and/or `partition by` you can `delete` using `row_number()` like so:

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, val int);
insert into t values (1,9),(2,8),(3,7),(4,6),(5,5);

delete 
from t
where id in (
  select id
  from (
    select id, row_number() over (order by val asc) as rn
    from t
    ) s
  where s.rn = 3);

select * from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XJHB50704

returns:

```
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   9 |
|  2 |   8 |
|  4 |   6 |
|  5 |   5 |
+----+-----+
```